# python selenium clicking based on alt attribute

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser, bots

I'm trying to make a bot which adds an item to your basket and checks out. I have a problem clicking on the item using Selenium in Python 3.6.5. I want to be able to click on an item based on its alt attribute of the img tag, so "Dek946uiqbq" here.

```html
<img src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/157783/vi/dek946uiQBQ.jpg" alt="Dek946uiqbq" width="81" height="81">
```

So far I have done this, but it doesn't work:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all')
linkElem = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Dek946uiqbq')
linkElem.click()
```

Am I using the wrong method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Dek946uiqbq` is not text, `find_element_by_link_text` can't detect it. Text looks like this in the html

```
<img src="..." alt="...">This is text</img>
```

To locate element by attribute you can use `css_selector`

```
linkElem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('[alt="Dek946uiqbq"]')
```

Or `xpath`

```
linkElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@alt="Dek946uiqbq"]')
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working now, for the next stage I want to add it to the basket - I've tried browser.find_element_by_name('commit') but it gives me a NoSuchElementException, when the HTML is this: <input type="submit" name="commit" value="add to basket" class="button">

Comment: @aboruchovas Try adding [explicit wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)